# How to deprioritize a font on Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, fonts

I have been studying Akkadian and therefore need to write cuneiform text on Linux. I have installed a cuneiform font for this purpose.

However, it seems that there is another font called "Steinberg Bravura" that has musical symbols assigned to cuneiform characters. See fc-list output below.

```sh
$ fc-list :charset=12000
/usr/share/fonts/gdouros-akkadian/Akkadian.ttf: Akkadian:style=Regular
/usr/share/fonts/steinberg-bravuratext-fonts/BravuraText.otf: Bravura Text:style=Normal,Regular
```

Due to this ill-behaving font, all of my programs display cuneiform characters using Bravura unless I specifically change the font to Akkadian, which I don't want to do or even can do with most programs.

I cannot remove Bravura since it's a dependency of MuseScore which I also use daily.

How can I deprioritize Bravura in the font stack so that my cuneiform characters are displayed correctly?

I'm using Fedora 36.